# Current Transformer giving a reading when not clamped around a wire

Tags: arduino, sensor, current, transformer, current-measurement

A [split core current transformers](http://www.lem.com/hq/en/component/option,com_catalog/task,displayserie/serie,TT/output_type,/) is currently clamped around a live wire. One end of the transformer's output wires are connected to the analog pin of an Arduino and the other end has a 2.5V bias created by tapping between two 470k ohm resistors connected across `GND` and `+5V` of the Arduino.

[image]

If the current transformer is removed and `A0` is connected to the 2.5V point, Arduino gives a steady reading of `512` which is expected..

However when the current transformer is connected as described and `A0` is connected to the other end of the current transformer (as described), Arduino readings of pin `A0` will fluctuate around between `503` and `519` even when the clamped wire is unplugged or even when removed.

What is causing the current transformer to still give a reading?

Additionally, if we have 2-3 [split core current transformers](http://www.lem.com/hq/en/component/option,com_catalog/task,displayserie/serie,TT/output_type,/) about 1-3 inches apart from each other, will the readings of each current transformers be affected?

Comment: Does the "spurious" reading reduce when the clamp is closed? What range of readings do you get when operated properly with a decent load current?

Answer (score 4):

The secondary of the transformer may pick up some 60Hz signal from the mains even if mains is not actually threaded through it.  The signal would be weaker than if the mains were threaded through the core.  Try moving the mains wire closer and further from the transformer.  If you move it further, the signal should reduce.  You may be picking up the signal from the wiring in the building.

Suppose, you have one of these transformers clamped on a wire W1, while another wire W2 is close by but not going through the transformer.  The transformer may sense both of these wires.  The signal from W1 will be stronger than from W2, though.

Comment: Is there a way to shield the transformer from sensing the other wires?

Comment: Thought I'd also mention: If you're measuring power, you may well have the split-core clamp near other transformers, from which it may be subject to their fluctuating magnetic field.